# Document must be a valid JavaScript object in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

Simply trying to set a new field to the value of an existing field in the same document without iterating  (can do iteration but aggregation pipeline seems more efficient)

The aggrgation expression comes from mongodb aggregation builder and it previews fine there.

Code

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const agg = [
  {
    '$match': {}
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'old_price': '$price'
    }
  }, {}, {}];

const url= '...y';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
async function main() {
const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const dbName = 'mongodbVSCodePlaygroundDB';
const collname='test';
const coll = client.db(dbName).collection(collname);
const rset = await coll.updateMany(agg);
console.log(rset);
await client.close();
}

main()
  .then(console.log('ok'))
  .catch(console.error)
  .finally(() => client.close());
```

ERROR: MongoInvalidArgumentError: Document must be a valid JavaScript object

Occurs at this line:

```
const rset = await coll.updateMany(agg);
```

Any pointers on getting this to work?

Tried a number of variations with quotes and square braces

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: `updateMany()` doesn't take an array as its first (and only) argument. You should change `agg` to just be an array that contains only the `$set` stage and then change your call to be `updateMany({}, agg)` (assuming you are intending to try to update all documents)